# A Mapstruct mapper isn't injected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

There's something weird going on. My Mapstruct mapper is not being registered as a Spring component even though the IntelliJ UI says it is. It causes my controller test to fail

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("api/v1/registration")
@Tag(
        name = "Registration Controller", description = "Register client in the application"
)
public class RegistrationController {
    private final RegistrationClient registrationClient;
    private final ClientDtoMapperImpl clientDtoMapper;
```

```java
@Mapper
        (componentModel = "spring")
public interface ClientDtoMapper {
  UserDto clientDtoToUserDto(ClientDto client);
}
```

```
WARN [api-gateway,,] 17348 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationController' defined in file [C:\Users\NadChel\IdeaProjects\api-gateway\target\classes\by\afinny\apigateway\controller\userservice\RegistrationController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'by.afinny.apigateway.mapper.ClientDtoMapper#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [by.afinny.apigateway.mapper.ClientDtoMapper]: Specified class is an interface
```

If I try to inject the class directly

```java
// annotations
public class RegistrationController {
    private final RegistrationClient registrationClient;
    private final ClientDtoMapperImpl clientDtoMapper; // injecting the implementation
```

I get this exception

```
WARN [api-gateway,,] 13612 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationController' defined in file [C:\Users\NadChel\IdeaProjects\api-gateway\target\classes\by\afinny\apigateway\controller\userservice\RegistrationController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'by.afinny.apigateway.mapper.ClientDtoMapperImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

My pom must be correct

```xml
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

<!-- ... -->

  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
<!-- ... -->
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

<!-- ... -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- ... -->

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
              <version>0.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
              <version>2.6.6</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>
              -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
            </compilerArg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

The implementation must be a visible Spring bean, according to IntelliJ. Screenshots are frowned upon on SO, but I wanted to show you the UI elements that imply everything should work fine

[image]

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: What error did you receive? Please provide a complete stack trace

Comment: @MaksimEliseev I included the key part of the stacktrace, the root exception. The rest of it is not going to provide much useful insight

Comment: I had the exact same problem yesterday. The error was typos in the POM. No other change was required such as componentModel = "spring".

Answer (score 4):

Try running `mvn clean install` after you added `componentModel = 'spring'` in the `@Mapper` annotation and try again with the first approach, using the interface. Sometimes, cached data or generated files can cause problems.